# Converting a CNN from classification to log regression?

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, logistic-regression, tflearn

I put together a CNN using tflearn that classifies images in terms of their scaling from some original resolution (I.e. 50%, 70%, etc.) just to see what kind of accuracy I could get for this problem. I’m new to machine learning so I figured it would be a good way to start towards the overall goal of having the network determine the scaling at any level, not just the few I generated for classification.

After getting a reasonable level of accuracy I decided to convert to model to do logistical regression instead of classification, but I’m having a few issues both in theory and application. First, what should the labels even look like? Before I was using a one-hot array for the 5 different classes, but obviously that’s not applicable anymore. Should the labels be the scale factor (I.e. 0.5 for 50%, etc.) or something else? Then, should the model itself really look any different? It’s my understanding that I should really only be tweaking the cost function and backprop/optimization portions, as well as changing the output to be one value instead of five. Again, I’m rather new so I’d appreciate any advice on this.

Thank you!

(Also, I didn't include any code here because I feel like these questions are pretty general and my code is not really that special or involved, but if anyone needs to see it in order to help with answering/giving advice, just ask and I will post some of it here.)

Answer (score 0):

Usually in classification problems, your output will use the softmax function to generate "probabilities". In neural networks, to convert this to a regression approach, remove the softmax layer and change the output dimension from the number of classes you had previously (5) to 1. Training this should yield a vector of shape [batchsize x 1] that can be fed to your loss function with labels of the same shape containing the real-valued scale factor, assuming this is indeed what the model is trying to predict.

Comment: Thanks for the help. From what you're saying it seems like what I had guessed is the right way to go about it. The only deviation in the approach I've actually put into code so far is that while I did remove the softmax activation for that layer, I didn't take the layer out completely, I just changed the activation to sigmoid, but I'm assuming that's what needs to be done anyway?

Comment: Yes, your fully-connected output layer should remain, only the softmax should be removed, sorry if that wasn't clear. If your output will always fall in the range [0,1] then sigmoid nonlinearity in this layer is acceptable, though a nonlinearity is  not always necessary in the fully-connected output layer.